# Avoid specific css to be minified in MVC bundleconfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

In MVC BundleConfig.cs, when the `debug=false` or `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` it minifies the scripts and css files, but what if I want explicitly avoid specific one that should not be minified?

I have one problematic css file which is broken as soon as it is minified. So I would like to keep only that one as it is. (please do not suggest fixing that broken css etc...)

I mean as an example:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( 
                    "~/Content/myStyle1.css",
                    "~/Content/myStyle2.css",
                    "~/Content/myStyle3.css",
                    "~/Content/myStyleDoNotMinify.css" 
                ));
```

How to exclude the last one to not be minified, but still included?

Should I just not use the bundle config at all for that specific css?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested you can link the file "myStyleDoNotMinify.css" separately without adding into the bundle. If you would like to include all the css files in a folder and just exclude this file you may use the ignore list.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/*.css"));

BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("myStyleDoNotMinify.css", OptimizationMode.Always);
```

Comment: thanks but ignore would not work because the css would not be loaded at all. I still want to add it without minifying it.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I suggested ignore list just in case you have so many other css files in the folder and that make it easy to load everything except the file in question. You need to link that file separately since you are ignoring it.